# Error trying to upload a photo using carrier wave and s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave

This is my error in the terminal,

```
Excon::Error::Socket (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)):

app/controllers/properties_controller.rb:15:in `create'
```

this is the view page

```
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)
```

this is my fog file,

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        # required
  config.fog_credentials = {
provider:              'AWS',                        # required
aws_access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_APP_KEY'],                        # required
aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_APP_SECRET'],                        # required
region:                'us-east-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
host:                  's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
endpoint:              's3-external-1.amazonaws.com' # optional, defaults to nil
}
config.fog_directory  = ENV['AWS_BUCKET_NAME']                          # required
config.fog_public     = false                                        # optional, defaults to true
config.fog_attributes = { cache_control: "public, max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" } # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

any help will be much appreciated

```
  def create
@property = Property.new(property_params)

  if @property.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end


  private
  def property_params
if params[:property][:amenities].class == Array
  params[:property][:amenities] = params[:property][:amenities].join(",")
end
params.require(:property).permit(:property_name, :city, :ppm, :images, :user_id, :amenities, {property_images: []})

end
```

it wants me to add more details, so I have tried changing the regions etc...

also do I need 'excon'

Comment: Hi Dave, could you provide the `create` method from your properties controller?

Comment: Just added. thanks

Comment: I think you need to change the CarrierWave configuration option `host` to point to `'s3.amazonaws.com'` instead of `'s3.example.com'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the CarrierWave configuration option host to point to `'s3.amazonaws.com'` instead of `'s3.example.com'`

Comment: Great that seems to have sorted that error, I'm now left with this:                 bad URI(is not URI?): ://(my-bucket-name).s3.amazonaws.com:

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your configuration endpoint,

You don't need host entry.
I have modified the endpoint to use the standard s3 url.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        # required
  config.fog_credentials = {
provider:              'AWS',                        # required
aws_access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_APP_KEY'],                        # required
aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_APP_SECRET'],                        # required
region:                'us-east-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
endpoint:              's3.amazonaws.com' # optional, defaults to nil
}
config.fog_directory  = ENV['AWS_BUCKET_NAME']                          # required
config.fog_public     = false                                        # optional, defaults to true
config.fog_attributes = { cache_control: "public, max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" } # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

Referenced Documentation:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Use-minio-with-Carrierwave

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1802

Hope it helps.